# OPTIONS request being made for $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I have the following code which,currently im running on my local machine.I am making a call to a php script called getxml.php,which should send the contents of an xml file as the response.

But,instead of a GET request, in Firebug i see that an OPTIONS request is being made, like
**OPTIONS getxml.php** . I think im not making a cross domain Ajax request,but still am facing this problem . Any way to fix this ?

```
var employee_list = new Object; 
$(function(){
                $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"http://localhost/projectname/getxml.php",
                datatype:"xml",
                success: function(xml){
                    $(xml).find('employee').each(function(){
                        var name_text = $(this).find('name').text();
                        var url_text = $(this).find('url').text();
                        employee_list[name_text] = url_text;
                        $('<li></li>').html(name_text + ' (' + url_text + ')').appendTo('#update-target ol');

                    });
                } //closing function        
             }); //closing $.ajax

}); //closing $(
```

**getxml.php**

```
<?php
    //Send the xml file as response
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    readfile('employee_results.xml');
?>
```

Thank You

Comment: where is the xml in php? you just send some headers

Comment: Thanks for the reply streetparade.The readfile() function reads the contents of the xml file and sends it.

Comment: There really is no such thing as an OPTIONS request in HTTP. Even if you set `datatype:"OPTIONS"` the underlying XHR object wouldn't understand that. What leads you to believe the HTTP verb is "OPTIONS"?

Comment: what happens when you view the getxml.php url directly in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure getxml.php exists. OPTIONS usually means you have a slight misspelling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ramblingwood. Ive made sure getxml.php exists.My project folder contains a js sub-folder,getxml.php,the xml file itself and an index.html page containing the above javascript.The js sub-folder contains the jquery library

Answer (score 1):

change `datatype` to `dataType` and see if that fixes your problem. The rest of the code looks right.

edit:  also, I'm not a PHP pro, but I wrote a map application which uses a similar approach.  To return xml, I used:

```
header("Status: 200");
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo  file_get_contents($q,0); /*$q is the query/filename*/  
exit();
```

I remember reading somewhere that `header("Status: 200");` was required.

edit:  Here is how I've done the same thing.  I hope this helps.

```
 /* call ajax method to retrieve earthquakes */
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../getxml.php?q=" + xmlLocation, 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
                /* Retrieve all needed values from XML */
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var summary = $(this).find('summary').text();
                var coord = $(this).find('georss\\:point').eq(0).text();
                if(!coord){var coord = $(this).find('point').text();}; 
                var points = coord.split(' ');
                var latitude = parseFloat(points[0]);
                var longitude = parseFloat(points[1]);  
                var htmlString = "<div class=\"infowindow\"><b>" + 
                                title + "</b>" + "<p>" + summary + "<br></div>";
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                 position: myLatlng,
                 map: map,
                 title: title
                });
                markers[markers.length] = marker;
                addInfoWindow(marker, map, htmlString);

                $('#output').text("Showing " + markers.length + " earthquakes");
            });/*  end each */
        }
    }); /* end $.ajax */
```

The php file is exactly as I posted above, but with "security" to respond only to ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jim. I made that change you suggested,but still have the same problem :(

Comment: That's weird.  I'm going to add an example of how I pull Earthquake XML feeds from USGS.gov for an Earthquake tracker I made: http://www.ipreferjim.com/maps/quakes.html